# Microsoft graph api group/members/manager?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

any idea why this works
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager` 
and not this
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/members?$expand=manager`

i get a "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'manager' on type 'microsoft.graph.directoryObject'."

Any chance i can cast directoryObjects in users?

I want to get all users and their manager for one group, i would like to do it without an extra call for each user :/

Maybe there is a way to start from user api and not group api but still filter on group membershipt? i dont know :'(

i tried the /members/manager, expand=manager... in v1 and beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/members` returns a collection of `microsoft.graph.directoryObject` entities.

Members of a group can be `users`, `organizational contacts`, `devices`, `service principals` and other `groups`.

Each of them has its own type derived from `microsoft.graph.directoryObject`, like `microsoft.graph.user`, `microsoft.graph.device`, etc.

Manager is a relationship related to user type. To be able to read the manager, you need to perform OData casting to users

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/microsoft.graph.user?$expand=manager
```

Inner select to return a subset of manager properties is supported.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/microsoft.graph.user?$expand=manager($select=id,displayName)
```